# Iterating over list of objects

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have a list with lists with objects inside them, and i need to iterate over each object in all lists. This is what i have tried but doesnt work the way i intend it to.

```
dict_values([[&lt;mapvis.store.Node object at 0x14fd370&gt;, &lt;mapvis.store.Node object at 0x13c4270&gt;], [&lt;mapvis.store.Node object at 0x14fd930&gt;, &lt;mapvis.store.Node object at 0x14fd490&gt;], ])
```

Js function

```
function displayRoads(map) {
  {% for create_lat_lng in get_lat_lng %}
        {% for lat_lng in create_lat_lng %}
        var points = new google.maps.MVCArray();
        points.push(new google.maps.LatLng(lat_lng[0].lat, lat_lng[0].lng));
        points.push(new google.maps.LatLng(lat_lng[1].lat, lat_lng[1].lng));
        createPolyline(map, points);
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
}
```

Html thats generated. I want it to have actual values intstead of lat_lng[0].lng

```
function displayRoads(map) {
    var points = new google.maps.MVCArray();
    points.push(new google.maps.LatLng(lat_lng[0].lat, lat_lng[0].lng));
    points.push(new google.maps.LatLng(lat_lng[1].lat, lat_lng[1].lng));
    createPolyline(map, points);
...
..
...
}
```

Comment: Added more info in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `{{ variable }}` syntax.

```
function displayRoads(map) {
  {% for create_lat_lng in get_lat_lng %}
      {% for lat_lng in create_lat_lng %}
        var points = new google.maps.MVCArray();
        points.push(new google.maps.LatLng({{ lat_lng.0.lat }}, {{ lat_lng.0.lng }}));
        points.push(new google.maps.LatLng({{ lat_lng.1.lat }}, {{ lat_lng.1.lng }}));
        createPolyline(map, points);
      {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
}
```

Just to clarify, `{{ lat_lng.0.lat }}` means access index zero on the `lat_lng` variable, and then get the value of the dictionary key `lat`. So the code above assumes  `lat_lng` is a array/tuple containing dictionaries.

Comment: It gives me no values like this        points.push(new google.maps.LatLng(, ));
        points.push(new google.maps.LatLng(, ));

Comment: Is `lat_lng` an array or dictionary? By your code I assumed it was an array. You could try `{{ lat_lng.lat }}` and `{{ lat_lng.lng }}`, if it is a dictionary. I need to know the actual structure of the `lat_lng` variable to give you a precise answer.